# Why does the Task.WhenAny not throw an expected TimeoutException?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

Please, observe the following trivial code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        try
        {
            Task.WhenAny(RunAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timed out");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: " + sw.Elapsed);
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        await Observable.StartAsync(async ct =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                await Task.Delay(500, ct);
                Console.WriteLine("Inside " + i);
            }
            return Unit.Default;
        }).Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
    }
}
```

Running it outputs:

```
Inside 0
Inside 1
Elapsed: 00:00:01.1723818
Press Enter to exit
```

Note, no **Timed out** message.

Now, if I replace `Task.WhenAny` with `Task.WhenAll` here is what I get:

```
Inside 0
Inside 1
Timed out
Elapsed: 00:00:01.1362188
Press Enter to exit
```

Note the presence of the **Timed out** message this time.

And, if I remove the `Task.WhenAll` wrapper at all and call `RunAsync` directly:

```
Inside 0
Inside 1
Timed out
Elapsed: 00:00:01.1267617
Press Enter to exit
```

The **Timed out** message is there, as expected.

So what is the deal with `Task.WhenAny` ? It obviously interrupts the asynchronous method, but where is the `TimeoutException`?

Comment: Why are you using `.Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, firstly it is equivilent to `Task.Result` and secondly you are likely to be eaten by a grue.

Comment: @Aron It isn't equivalent. It throws the actual exception. But yes, it's still blocking and could lead to deadlocks.

Comment: [Task.getAwaiter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter(v=vs.110).aspx): `This method is intended for compiler use rather than for use in application code.`

Comment: @sstan - I know that and yet it is the only true blocking equivalent to `await`. `.Result` or `.Wait()` have a different exception handling semantics.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`Task.WhenAny` doesn't rethrow exceptions from the individual tasks (unlike `Task.WhenAll`):

> "The returned task will complete when any of the supplied tasks has completed. The returned task will always end in the `RanToCompletion` state with its `Result` set to the first task to complete. This is true even if the first task to complete ended in the `Canceled` or `Faulted` state."

From [`Task.WhenAny`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160383(v=vs.110).aspx)

That means that it will complete successfully no matter what without any type of exceptions.

To actually rethrow the exception of the individual completed task you need to `await` the returned task itself:

```
var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks); // no exception
await completedTask; // possible exception
```

Or in your case:

```
Task.WhenAny(RunAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Oh man, it returns a `Task<Task>`. Now it makes sense, but why does it have such a strange return type?

Comment: @mark The outer task is there so you could await it. the inner task is there for you to get the first completed task as the result. When you use `Task.WhenAny` you probably want to know which task finished first, or what its result is.

Comment: Does that mean you can legitimately write `await await Task.WhenAny(tasks)` @i3arnon ?!

Comment: Note that while you can legitimately write `await await Task.WhenAny(tasks)` only first taks's result/state gets checked this way.

Comment: ...which is important in case of exceptions to prevent UnobservedTaskExceptions.

Comment: OMG, thx for this. At first I thought wtf is happening when no exception was thrown.